# Rewriting `admin` to `admin.php` and everything else to `main.php`

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite:

- `http://mydomain` to `./main.php`
- `http://mydomain/abc` to `./main.php/abc`
- `http://mydomain/abc?def=xyz` to `./main.php/abc?def=xyz`
- `http://mydomain/admin` to `./admin.php`
- `http://mydomain/admin/abc` to `./admin.php/abc`

and here's my current .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^$ ./main.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ ./main.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin$ ./admin.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/$ ./admin.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ ./admin.php/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ ./main.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

But I keep getting **403 Forbidden** error when accessing `http://mydomain`, what did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
# don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)$ admin.php/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you redirect "admin" to "./admin.php"? If I'm right, this redirect would result into an URL like: http://domain.com/./admin.php - is this correct?

Further I'm unsure, because "admin" is part of "^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$" which you use in your last rewrite rule, hence "admin" would also be redirected to "./main.php".

You might want to enable the rewrite log to have a deeper look what the rewrite module is doing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite_log"
RewriteLogLevel 5
```

It might also help to look into /var/log/apache/error.log or access.log in order to figure out the rewritten URL.